# Updating a database automatically using ColdFusion

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, cfml

I need to carry out certain updates to MSSQL field data at times determined by certain events, e.g. after 200 new records have been added.

`CFSCHEDULE` refers to a certain date and time, not the date and time of an event.

I cannot find anything in the Adobe documentation.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing purely updates to data fields within MSSQL server based on events that happen in SQL Server there is NO need for any coldfusion code. Your best course of action would be to use a trigger on the database table you are interested in along with some kind of helper table.

e.g. You could set up a helper table dbo.MY_HELPER with a column called rowsSinceLastEvent 
a trigger on your target table could then check on each insert what the row count is since your last event and either fire an event if your target number of rows has been reached or bump up the row count number.

The trigger definition would look something like this. (This is just pseudo code)

```
DECLARE @rowsSinceLastUpdate INT

SELECT @rowsSinceLastUpdate = h.rowsSinceLastUpdate
FROM dbo.MY_HELPER h

IF @rowsSinceLastUpdate > 200
BEGIN
/* UPDATE ANY REQUIRED COLUMNS OR EXECUTE A STOREDPROCEDUT */
UPDATE dbo.MY_HELPER SET rowsSinceLastUpdate = 0
END ELSE BEGIN
UPDATE dbo.MY_HELPER SET rowsSinceLastUpdate = rowsSinceLastUpdate + 1
END
```

If you have to use coldfusion depending on your use case you may have to either do some kind of polling on the database or build a event gateway that monitors your database.